# UI autocomplete and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

This is my first question on the site, but I have a real problem. Im rewriting the code of my website to make it work on IE... And on IE8 only this code for a multiple autocomplete input crashes :

```
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete,
{
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items )
    {
        var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item )
        {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
$( "#form_rech" ).catcomplete({
    source: function(get, response) {
        $.getJSON('rom_new_php_recup.php?action=big_search',{ q: get.term; }, function(result) {
            response($.map(result, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.label.replace(/\\\'/g,"'"),
                    category: item.category,
                    hash: item.hash
                }
            }));
        });
    },
    select: function( event, ui) {
        document.location.hash = ui.item.hash;
    }
});
```

After e a few tests it seams ton come from the line :

```
$.getJSON('rom_new_php_recup.php?action=big_search',{ q: get.term; }, function(result)
```

And maybe specially from `,{ q: get.term; },`

Do you have any ideas to correct this ?
Thanks a lot !
Romain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon after `get.term`. IE is notoriously strict when processing JSON.